# Find out the value of a string using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

There is html code

```
</DIV>
   <CENTER><div id="div_errorh">#</div></CENTER>
   <table width="100%">
   <tr>
    <td width="74%" style="vertical-align:top;">
     <TABLE class="MainTable" CELLPADDING="3" CELLSPACING="0">
     <TBODY id="MAIN_TABLE">
     <TR><TH></TH><TH></TH><TH></TH>
     <TR class=Row2><TD ALIGN=LEFT class="" >String_1</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT class="" >Value of line 1</TD><TD ALIGN=LEFT></TD></TR>
<TR class=Row1><TD ALIGN=LEFT class="" >String_2</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT class="" >Value_of_line_2</TD><TD ALIGN=LEFT></TD></TR>
<TR class=Row2><TD ALIGN=LEFT class="" >String_3</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT class="" >Value_of_line_3</TD><TD ALIGN=LEFT><B><A 
<TR class=Row1><TD ALIGN=LEFT class="" >String_4</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT class="" >Value_of_line_4</TD><TD ALIGN=LEFT><B><A 
<TR class=Row2><TD ALIGN=LEFT class="" >String_5</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT class="" >Value_of_line_5</TD><TD ALIGN=LEFT></TD></TR>
<TR class=Row1><TD ALIGN=LEFT class="" >&nbsp;</TD><TD ALIGN=LEFT class="" ></TD><TD ALIGN=LEFT></TD></TR>
```

I need to find out the value of **Value_of_line_5** using **BeautifulSoup**.

I ask for help

Comment: "I need to find out the value of **Value_of_line_5**" what does this mean?  What value are you trying to extract exactly?

Comment: What chlanges do you face with? Please start with https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: I need to find out information from the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if your HTML tag is really incomplete. If so, please try the following code. I completed the HTML tag before extracting it.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''
 <TABLE class="MainTable" CELLPADDING="3" CELLSPACING="0">
     <TBODY id="MAIN_TABLE">
     <TR><TH></TH><TH></TH><TH></TH>
     <TR class=Row2><TD ALIGN=LEFT class="" >String_1</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT class="" >Value of line 1</TD><TD ALIGN=LEFT></TD></TR>
<TR class=Row1><TD ALIGN=LEFT class="" >String_2</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT class="" >Value_of_line_2</TD><TD ALIGN=LEFT></TD></TR>
<TR class=Row2><TD ALIGN=LEFT class="" >String_3</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT class="" >Value_of_line_3</TD><TD ALIGN=LEFT><B><A 
<TR class=Row1><TD ALIGN=LEFT class="" >String_4</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT class="" >Value_of_line_4</TD><TD ALIGN=LEFT><B><A 
<TR class=Row2><TD ALIGN=LEFT class="" >String_5</TD><TD ALIGN=RIGHT class="" >Value_of_line_5</TD><TD ALIGN=LEFT></TD></TR>
<TR class=Row1><TD ALIGN=LEFT class="" >&nbsp;</TD><TD ALIGN=LEFT class="" ></TD><TD ALIGN=LEFT></TD></TR>
</TBODY>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
doc['html'] = doc.replaceReg(doc.html,'</TH>\s*<TR','</TH></TR><TR')
doc['html'] = doc.replaceReg(doc.html,'<A\s*<TR','<A></TR><TR')
trs = doc.selects('TBODY#MAIN_TABLE>TR') 
value = trs[5].TDs[1].text
print (value)
```

Result:

```
Value_of_line_5
```

Comment: I get HTML from a variable and use this code to extract all strings and their values:
```
main_text = page

soup = BeautifulSoup(main_text, 'lxml')
MainTable = soup.find('table', {'class' : 'MainTable'})
tr = MainTable.find('MainTable' > 'tr:nth-child(5)')
#soup.find_all('tr', {'class' : 'Row2'}, {'align="RIGHT"'})
tr = tr.text

print(tr)
```
The problem is that no matter how I edit it, it only turns out to me to find out all the lines and all the values ​​of these lines ...

Comment: Maybe it's because your html label is incomplete

Comment: This code works, but it creates the spider.log file, the db directory, and the config.db file in it. Can this be turned off?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know yet. I'll look for it. Because this is a crawler framework, data extraction is only a part of it.

Comment: Thank you, I will be waiting for your reply.

Comment: Good news, the new version corrects this problem. Just run this command: pip install -U simplified_scrapy

Answer (score 0):

This will give the values for 4 and 5, then you can check with if_else:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(code, "html.parser")
a = soup.find_all('a')
for i in a:
    tds = i.find_all('td')
    print(tds[1].text)
```

Comment: Nothing happens